# Constantly monitor a program/process using Python

Tags: python, scheduling, daemon, cron-task

I am trying to constantly monitor a process which is basically a Python program. If the program stops, then I have to start the program again. I am using another Python program to do so.

For example, say I have to constantly run a process called `run_constantly.py`. I initially run this program manually, which writes its process ID to the file "PID" (in the location out/PROCESSID/PID).

Now I run another program which has the *following code* to monitor the program `run_constantly.py` from a Linux environment:

```
def Monitor_Periodic_Process():

    TIMER_RUNIN = 1800
    foo = imp.load_source("Run_Module","run_constantly.py")
    PROGRAM_TO_MONITOR = ['run_constantly.py','out/PROCESSID/PID']
    while(1):
        # call the function checkPID to see if the program is running or not
        res = checkPID(PROGRAM_TO_MONITOR)
        # if res is 0 then program is not running so schedule it
        if (res == 0):
            date_time = datetime.now()
            scheduler.add_cron_job(foo.Run_Module, year=date_time.year, day=date_time.day, month=date_time.month, hour=date_time.hour, minute=date_time.minute+2)
            scheduler.start()
            scheduler.get_jobs()
            time.sleep(TIMER_NOT_RUNIN)
            continue
        else:
            #the process is running sleep and then monitor again
            time.sleep(TIMER_RUNIN)
            continue
```

I have not included the `checkPID()` function here. `checkPID()` basically checks if the process ID still exists (i.e. if the program is still running) and if it does not exist, it returns `0`. In the above program, I check if `res == 0`, and if so, then I use Python's scheduler to schedule the program. However, the major problem that I am currently facing is that the process ID of this program and the `run_constantly.py` program *turns to be same* once I schedule the `run_constantly.py` using the `scheduler.add_cron_job()` function. So if the program `run_constantly.py` crashes, the following program still thinks that the `run_constantly.py` is running (since both process IDs are same), and therefore continues to go into the else loop to sleep and monitor again.

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue?  Is there a simple way to constantly monitor a program and reschedule it when it has crashed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many programs that can do this.

On Ubuntu there is [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) (installed by default)

Lots of people like http://supervisord.org/

[monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) as mentioned by @nathan

If you are looking for a python alternative there is a library that has just been released called [circus](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.5.2.1/) which looks interesting.

And pretty much every linux distro probably has one of these built in.

The choice is really just down to which one you like better, but you would be far better off using one of these than writing it yourself.

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 on supervisord. I use it and its really easy and cross platform.

Comment: @Mark Lakewood Thanks, Monit seems to be pretty interesting, although it lacks proper documentation. It works pretty neat

Comment: writing one ourselves allows us to extend it to suit our need (e.g. log the data for visualize them later)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to control the monitored program directly from python instead of using cron, have a look at the [**subprocess** module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) :

```
The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes,
connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.
```

Check examples like [*track process status with python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408627/track-process-status-with-python) on SO for examples and references.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use monit
http://mmonit.com/monit/

It monitors processes and restarts them (and other things.)

Comment: monit can do a lot of usefull thinks.

Comment: But anyway how is your scheduler run the application? It is not clear from your code sample. To resolve problems with PIDs you have run it correctly in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add a more versatile solution, which is one that I personally use all the time as well.

It's name is `Immortal` (source is at https://github.com/immortal/immortal)

To have it monitor and instantly restart a program if it stops, simply run the following command:

```
immortal <command>
```

So in your case I would run `run_constantly.py` like so:

```
immortal python run_constantly.py
```

The command `ps aux | grep run_constantly.py` should return 2 process IDs, one for the `Immortal` command, and one for the separate command `Immortal` started (just the regular command. As long as the Immortal process is running, `run_constantly.py` will stay running.