# Scaling workers with RabbitMQ

Tags: php, linux, rabbitmq, scaling

I have implemented rabbitMQ in my current application to handle asynchroneous jobs that are handled by workers.

So far so good everything works great, but my current problem is that i need to manually start all workers from CLI and painfully monitor queue size to scale the worker pool for each job type across all mahcines.
Also, if for some reason, all workers for a certain job type die or something alike, there is no way in my current implementation to "heal" from this status and recreate a pool apart from manually starting more workers from CLI.

My question is simple : is there an application / deamon for *nix systems that can handle that for me ?
I need something to control queue size and worker pool's health across multiple servers, spawning them up and down according to an initial setup.

Do i have to write that myself ?

Thanks

Comment: Look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13598749/1461984